# import not working even after __init__.py file python

Tags: python, import, init

I have a file structure like below.

```
Project/
    Main/
        __init__.py
        Test/
            __init__.py
            file1.py
        Utils/
            __init__.py
            file2.py
```

In file1.py I have `from Main.Utils.file2 import SomeClass`

If I run: python file1.py I am getting error: `ImportError: No module named Main.Utils.file2`

I even tried `import Main.Utils.file2`, this also gives me error.

Checked PYTHONPATH, I have Project in the path.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong ...

Comment: because `Project` directory has to be in the PATH.

Answer (score 0):

you can not do

```
from Project.Utils.file2 import SomeClass
```

since **Project** is not a module it self. if you want Project as a module it self. you have to add it in your **PYTHONPATH**

try this:

```
from Utils.file2 import SomeClass
```